# Which Eclipse IDE do I have? (i.e. Neon, Luna, etc.)

Tags: eclipse

How do I know which Eclipse IDE I have (i.e. Neon, Luna, etc.)? I'm not talking about the the version. I know that I have version 2021-09 (4.21.0). I want to install new software but I don't know what to put at the end of the following,
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/?????????.

What I'm really trying to do is add javascript, node, python, c++, etc. to the options in the following screenshot.
[image]

I think if I knew which Eclipse release I had, I would be able to add the things I want to the New Project Wizard. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked menu -> help -> about or something else?

Comment: Eclipse stopped naming them a while go. Now they date-stamp them.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-09/other_stuff. Eg `https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-09/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers`

Comment: By the way, don't spam tags.

Comment: I didn't mean to spam tags. Any suggestions on how to avoid that moving forward?

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out in the comments Eclipse changed its naming conventions. Here it the wiki that provided the answer I was looking for, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software). On that page you can find the Version Name based on the Platform Version. I have (at the time of writing this) version 2021-09 (4.21.0). So for me, I used  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-09.

I then realized that all I had to do was go to Help -> Install New Software... -> click the dropdown at the end of the Work With: text field. This revealed --All Available Sites--. This allowed me to install the additional languages I needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).